# showing the totals of a particular column below the data using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

i Work with an excel template in which i have to make the totals of a particular column. This will be repeated several times in a day. I want automate the template by which it will automatically calculate the totals and display below to the data.

Comment: Can you add some code you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically setting the sum formula in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738818/dynamically-setting-the-sum-formula-in-excel)